# AWS Linux: ensure that flaky script keeps running

Tags: python, linux, bash, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a nanny script, to use in AWS's Linux terminal, to run a python script that can be a bit flakey at times. I am very new to using the terminal / bash, etc, so I could be missing something totally obvious / second nature to others.  Here is what I have:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

while true:
    script.py
    sleep 1  # pause, so if script.py immediately dies we don't burn a core
```

I put the above code in a runProgram.sh file, located in the same directory as my python program.   I then went into the terminal, and ran:

```
chmod -x runProgram.sh
```

followed by:

```
bash runProgram.sh
```

The terminal throws the following error:

> "line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file".

I took the bash code right [from a stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833154/linux-check-if-python-script-is-running-in-screen-and-run-if-not) though, so I'm not sure what I'm missing in terms of syntax etc.  any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you reference the other answer here?

Comment: I think runProgram.sh is with CRLF line terminators.

Comment: added the link.    I'm not sure what you mean by CRLF line terminators?   I'm totally new at this.

Comment: Also - why not have the while loop inside the python script? & call the python script directly?

Comment: Also why are you doing `chmod -x run Program.sh`

Instead you must be giving it execute permissions by doing `chmod +x runProgram.sh`

Comment: Yeah, I seriously have no clue what I’m doing. If you could lay it out for me like you would a 5yr old that would be great.

Comment: Couple things.  **1** remove the space between `#!` and `/usr/bin/env`.  **2** you could put the loop and sleep directly in the python script (like @HariharanRagothaman mentionned).  **3** CRLF: when a file is created using a Windows editor (ex notepad) the files end with CR (carriage return) and LF (line feed).  These can cause issues when you run the files on Linux.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf for ways to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue, by directly copy-pasting the snippet you pasted.

Modified your script slightly. Feel free to copy-paste directly.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ True ]
do
  python3 script.py
done
```

[To know more about CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Also this is my current `bash` version

```
/tmp:$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Why does `chmod +x` do?

It essentially gives execute level permissions for your script of interest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So do I need to do that Chmod thing before I run this file?

Comment: Yes, for the bash script & the python script.

Comment: Is everything working for you now? @keynesiancross

Comment: I had to jump away from the computer - I’ll check back in 30min or so

Comment: Where should I write this file by the way?  I was transferring it from my PyCharm (windows) into my AWS Linux

Comment: If you are transferring from PyCharm to your AWS Linux - you are susceptible for CLRF issues again. I would say directly copy it to your linux console from this post (OR) change your Pycharm settings to support Linux line endings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246349/discussion-between-hariharan-ragothaman-and-keynesiancross).

Answer (score 0):

This command makes the file non executable:

```
chmod -x runProgram.sh
```

What you want to do is to make executable like so:

```
chmod +x runProgram.sh
```

Turn both, your shell script and python script executable.

then you can run it by typing `./runProgram.sh` or `bash runProgram.sh`.